# Do variables have to be defined in Python before use?

Tags: python, variables, variable-declaration

Is Python much like PHP in that I can call a variable and if it doesn't exist it will be created? Or I need to declare them?

Comment: You said "call a variable", but if you meant "assign to a variable", then yes, in python, as in PHP, the variable will be created dynamically.

Comment: Hint: Python does feature an interactive interpreter you get just by running "python" by itself - the interpreter, among other things is excelent for you to test these simple things by yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP if you call a variable and it doesn't exist, you'll get `Notice: Undefined variable`. This doesn't create it -- doing the same thing again still returns a warning.

```
php > echo $some_uninitialized_var;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: some_uninitialized_var in php shell code on line 1
php > echo $some_uninitialized_var;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: some_uninitialized_var in php shell code on line 1
```

In Python if you call a variable and it isn't initialized you'll get a `NameError`.  Same thing - it won't get created - you'll get `NameError` until you actually initialize it.

```
>>> print(some_uninitialized_var)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_uninitialized_var' is not defined

>>> print(some_uninitialized_var)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_uninitialized_var' is not defined
```

#### Initialization without declaration:

In both PHP and Python though, unlike say, C, you don't need to *declare* the variables before first using them, and that's perhaps what you meant.  You can just assign them and they'll be created on first assignment.

```
// PHP
$a_new_var = 12345;
// All is well...

# Python
a_new_var = 12345
# All is well...

// C
a_new_var = 12345;
// Crash! Horror! Compiler complains!
int a_new_var;
a_new_var = 12345;
// ok...
```

Comment: I'd sugest replacing "call a variable" with "use a variable"